# MySQL selecting text after last slash

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL column that holds a `VARCHAR` that looks like this:

```
folder1/folder2/<Entity>
```

For example:

```
folder1/folder2/Apple
folder1/folder2/Microsoft
```

Because I would like to perform a search on the entity field, I would like to add a column that just contains `entity` (and the query for `$searchTerm%`). How can I select that last part after the last `/` directly in MySQL?

I would like that column to just hold `Apple` and `Microsoft` from the example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
select substring_index(mysql_column, '/', -1)
```